# add picker on container extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi everyone I should add the Ext.form.field.Picker to my Custom Component but I can't figure out if it is possible.

```
createStructure: function () {
    this.add({
        xtype: 'container',
        cls: 'logo-avatar-messages',
        height: 50,
        maxHeight: 50,
        style: 'background-color: #ccc; border-radius: 50%; vertical-align: middle;',
        width: 50,
        layout: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'label',
                style: 'font-size: 25px; IMPORTANT!; color: #ffffff;',
                listeners: {
                    afterRender: function (component) {
                        var utente = userData.get('denominazione');
                        if (utente !== 'ND') {
                            var alias = utente.split(' ')[0][0] + utente.split(' ')[1][0];
                            component.setText(alias);
                        }
                    },

                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation available [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html) for the **pickerfield**:
"*An abstract class for fields that have a single trigger which opens a "picker" popup below the field, e.g. a combobox menu list or a date picker*".

So maybe what you are looking for is a [**combobox**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html), a field that extend/implement the pickerfield. You can heavy customize the template of each single row available for selection with the [tpl](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-tpl) config to show complex html elements without re-inventing the wheel.

To give you an example of what you can do with the tpl config, like showing an html table for each record available for selection:

```
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item" style="border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0;">',
                            '<table>',
                                '<tr>',
                                    '<th width="100">ORDER ID: </th><td>{orderId}</td>',
                                '</tr>',
                                '<tr>',
                                    '<th>ORDER TYPE: </th><td>{orderType}</td>',
                                '</tr>',
                                '<tr>',
                                    '<th>DESCRIPTION: </th><td><i>{orderDescription}</i></td>',
                                '</tr>',
                                '<tr>',
                                    '<th>DATE: </th><td>{orderDate:date("d/m/Y")}</td>',
                                '</tr>',
                            '</table>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</tpl>'),
```